# Html/Javascript - Onfocus event

Tags: javascript, html

So, I am attempting to ensure that the page I am working on works cross browser and to do this I have attempted to call the 'onfocus' event within `<script>` tags - Unfortunately what I have tried isn't working and currently I am unsure why. Any advice/feedback would be appreciated.

```html
<input name="searchField" placeholder="Search users" type="text" size="60"
    maxlength="150" id="SearchBox" style="margin-top:15px; height:auto;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!("placeholder" in document.createElement("input"))) {
        document.getElementsByName("searchField")[0].value = 'Search users';
        document.getElementsByName("searchField")[0].onfocus =
            'document.getElementsByName("searchField")[0].value="";';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you notice "serarchField" vs "searchField" ?

Comment: Oh dear god I'm stupid. Changing that now...

Comment: Do you really want to empty the field each time it is focused ? I'd recommend you to use an existing placeholder library.

Comment: Just updated it with the correct spelling and I am still having no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to add events is:

```
document.getElementsByName("searchField")[0].onfocus = function () {
    document.getElementsByName("searchField")[0].value = "";
                                // ^ fixed that typo
    this.value = ""; // also works, `this` is a magic variable
};
```

You can just keep typing JavaScript instead of assigning strings and relying on `eval`.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for that. Didn't know about the 'this' variable.

Comment: I think this should read as "The correct way to add events is.."

Comment: @hop, not quite. The correct way to add events is with `addEventListener` but that is a little bit more involved still.

Answer (score 0):

it's work..

```
<input name="searchField" placeholder="Search users" type="text" size="60" maxlength="150" id="SearchBox" style="margin-top:15px; height:auto;"/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        if (!("placeholder" in document.createElement("input")))
        {
            document.getElementsByName("searchField")[0].value='Search users';
            document.getElementsByName("searchField")[0].onfocus=function(){
                 document.getElementsByName("searchField")[0].value="";
            };
        }
    </script>
```